# A uniform distribution problem coming from higher dimensions

Tags: sequences-and-series, ergodic-theory

Thinking about an approximation problem related to random walks, the following question came up.

Suppose we have $m$ numbers $a_1, \ldots, a_m \in \mathbb{R}$ and that $b \in \mathbb{R}$ is not in the rational linear span of $a_1,\ldots, a_m$. For any fixed sufficiently small $\epsilon >0$, do there exist infinitely many integers $n \ge 1$ such that
$$
\left|nb - \sum_{j=1}^m l_ja_j\right| > \epsilon
$$
for all integers $m$-tuples $(l_1, \ldots, l_m) \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}^m$ with $0\le l_1 + l_2 + \cdots + l_m \le n$?

It appears to be some form of higher dimensional uniform distribution problem. In the case $m=1$, $a_1 = 1$ and $b$ is irrational then the answer is yes: for any $\epsilon < 1/2$ there are infinitely many $n$ such that
$$
\left| bn - m \right| > \epsilon
$$
for all $0 \le m\le n$ as the sequence $a_n = bn$ is uniformly distributed modulo $1$, i.e. the fractional part of $bn$ uniformly distributes over $[0,1)$.

Does anyone know if the above more general result is true? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing why you are imposing $l_1+\ldots+l_m\le n$. Under this condition, it is clear that if $b>\max(a_1,\ldots,a_m)$ your condition is true. If you don't impose the condition on the $l$'s, then the statement is true if the $a_j$'s are rationally dependent (basically like your example); and false if the $a_j$'s are rationally independent (basically like the postage stamp problem).

Comment: For the rationally independent case, by counting there are two sums of $a$'s that differ by less than $\epsilon$, say $s_1$ and $s_2$. Now $ks_1$, $(k-1)s_1+s_2$, $\ldots$, $ks_2$ differ pairwise by less than $\epsilon$. For sufficiently large $k$, the gap $ks_2-ks_1$ exceeds $a$. Now anything large is close to a multiple of $a$ plus one of these.